# How to show "raw" html code in a html page

Tags: html

Is this the only way to show html code:

```
<html><body>
    <div class="header-logo">
        <h2>Juan Fernando</h2>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it between `<pre> </pre>` tags